# How is The Godfather: Part III related to the Cavalleria Rusticana?

Tags: analysis, reference, the-godfather-3

In the finale of [*The Godfather: Part III*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099674/) *Vincent*'s "clearance" of the *Corleone* family's enemies and the assassination attempt on *Michael* is intertwined with the family attending a performance of the opera [*Cavalleria Rusticana*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalleria_rusticana) (in which *Anthony* performs). Additionally, the [German Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalleria_rusticana) says that the movie also cites many images and plots of this opera (*Vincent* biting into *Zasa*'s ear comes to mind).

But having only very superficial Wikipedia-based knowledge about the story of the *Cavalleria Rusticana*, I have difficulties to draw any further connections of it to the movie. Now while I don't want this question to get too broad or degrade into a mere list of each and every possible camera shot referencing the opera, **I'd like to know if there are any major references to the *Cavalleria Rusticana*'s story or its overall motifs in the *The Godfather: Part III*.**

Answer (score 6):

There are four major plot points/similarities to consider:

1. The lead character, Turiddu, was in the military (as was Michael) and
   is eventually killed in a duel (as in the attempt on Michael's
   life).
2. Honor plays a major role in Turiddu's death, as the duel was over a woman.
3. There is also a lot of betrayal/lies in the opera as the two women vie for Turridu's affection.  This, of course, parallels the entire trilogy as much of it is akin to a chess match between various Corleone's and their adversaries.
4. The opera also takes place in Sicily, the birthplace of La Cosa Nostra.